# CSS - table styling

Tags: html, css

I need a table style like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kemcj.png) and it must be responsive, is this possible?

[image]

- Border spaces are important, they should be 4px/640px

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi Thx for edit!

Comment: Does it need to be a table?  Can you use Canvas?

Comment: @CR41G14 no, It's not just a shape, cells will contain images, and users will click on them

Comment: @Noc Will be always the same size? 4x4?

Comment: @Noc I mean, how much rows/columns it will has.

Comment: @Error404 sorry I've misred it, columns are 4, but rows are not

Comment: @Noc please check my answer or fiddle link may be this can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
  var _size = document.getElementById("myTable").offsetWidth/160 + "px";
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.borderWidth = _size;
    x[i].style.height = x[i].offsetWidth + "px";
  }
};
```

```css
table {
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
 width: 25%;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:first-child td {
 border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
 border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child {
 border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child {
 border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">1</td>
    <td class="cell">2</td> 
    <td class="cell">3</td>
    <td class="cell">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">5</td>
    <td class="cell">6</td> 
    <td class="cell">7</td>
    <td class="cell">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">9</td>
    <td class="cell">10</td> 
    <td class="cell">11</td>
    <td class="cell">12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">13</td>
    <td class="cell">14</td> 
    <td class="cell">15</td>
    <td class="cell">16</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

find this path to get entire knowledge on table css

```
https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/
```

Comment: I couldn't find there